# OSM routing database with high quality data?

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, open-source-routing-machine

Our company is searching for a routing service which provides free OSM database (high quality routing data) and preferably also considers the traffic parameters (traffic flow, day etc. similar to no-OSM providers like  here, TomTom, Google Maps etc.). We did a quick check (measured the driving distance and time for a couple of GPS points in several countries) and could find out that the OSM-based providers (graphhopper, mapquest, openroute, OSRM, YOURS) probably don´t consider the traffic parameters in their calculations but only take the average (or maybe the fastest) driving speed into account. We found out that although the driving distance was similar to the not-OSM providers (negligible deviations) the driving time was much lower by OSM providers (that is why we suppose that the traffic parameters aren´t considered by OSM providers). Each month we generate more Mio. routing queries so cost per query is for us unthinkable. Of course we have to pay for the implementation but we would like to prefer an open source routing database (finally the Bing Maps routing API is partly based  on OSM database (together with here) so the quality of OSM should be acceptable). ESRI Map Direction API or MapBox Direction Map API also provide routing services with probably high quality routing data but we would like to prefer OSM because the price model of ESRI or Mapbox isn´t attractive for us.

Do you have some experience with OSM-providers regarding the quality of their routing databases?

Comment: Open Route Service use to include traffic information but I believe it had a number of issues. I still think they have plans to introduce it back some time unknown to me. Excluding traffic, ORS is the most accurate in tests I conducted earlier this year out of the providers you listed above.

Answer (score 3):

OSM data is typically always the same, independent of the provider or routing-engine. Routers can interpret this data in a different way and it is possible that providers will enhance / modify this data slightly.

Real-time traffic is not contained in OSM and must always come from an external source. This is the tricky part. You can try to add traffic data from http://opentraffic.io/ or TMC (Traffic Message Channel).

Update: Looks like the opentraffic.io project is dead.